# C# - Create User on Remote Machine in same Workgroup (not domain)

Tags: c#, active-directory, workgroup, windows-users

A windows user can be created on the local machine or in active directory using the .NET System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry class, but I need to create a user on a remote computer which is in the same workgroup.

Is there any way to achieve the following scenario?

1. The application will run and take administrator credentials from the User
2. The User's credentials will be used to access the remote computer to create the new user on the remote machine in the same workgroup

Can we achieve the above requirement without using the following methods:

1. Implementation of Active Directory and creating AD user on remote machine
2. Creating a utility app, placing it on a shared UNC path and executing this utility remotely on other computers that will create local accounts there

I can't use either of the above methods due to some limitations.

Comment: Have you looked at using PowerShell? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20186677/how-to-create-a-local-windows-user-account-using-remote-powershell

Comment: @RyanS yes. it can be done through PowerShell but it has some complications like It is not installed on some OS by default,  We need to activate Remote execution in PowerShell. We need to exclude it from the firewall, for Workgroup, the same account needs to exist on both machine. and some more considerations are there. 

My requirement is to run the installer on any machine where User will be created on another machine in the same network. (IP will be provided)